# JMETER - access variables set in .bash_profile

Tags: jmeter

I am using JMeter and I want to access a variable set in my .bash_profile

Is there any way I can do so.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can use Beanshell Pre Processor OR Beanshell Post Processor OR Beanshell Sampler

I tried to access JAVA_HOME, it works fine. Replace JAVA_HOME with your variable.

```
System.getenv("JAVA_HOME")
```

To access it in JMeter,

```
 vars.put("JAVAHOME", System.getenv("JAVA_HOME"));
```

Then in your test use ${JAVAHOME} to get the value.